# Is it possible to random_shuffle an array of int elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, shuffle

I was reading up on this : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/
and wondered if its possible to random_shuffle an array of int elements. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    cout << a << endl << endl;

    random_shuffle(a[0],a[9]);

    cout<<a;
}
```

I got this error:

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template
    'iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type *std::_Dist_type(_Iter)'.
```

My question are:

1. Is it possible to shuffle an int array using `random_shuffle`. If yes, I would like to learn how to do it.
2. Is `random_shuffle` only applicable to templates?
3. What does my error mean?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to pass pointers to `a[0]` and `a[10]`, not the elements themselves:

```
random_shuffle(&a[0], &a[10]); // end must be 10, not 9
```

In C++11, you can use `std::begin` and `std::end`:

```
random_shuffle(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

Comment: i know this sounds stupid but how do you know its pointers?? which part of the page say so??

Comment: @Computernerd, Pointers are random-access iterators, and it takes two iterators.

Comment: @ALL another qn: This method shuffles all the number when it is called once, is there any method which swaps 2 number only once when called??

Comment: @Computernerd, `std::swap`?

Comment: @Computernerd If you need to swap a few numbers to get another random permutation, you can call `next_permutation`. It often swaps only two items, but may swap more, or none at all (in which case it returns `false`).

Comment: To shuffle the entire array, you should call `random_shuffle(&a[0], &a[10]);` rather than `random_shuffle(&a[0], &a[9]);`

Comment: @Mankarse Thanks, I did not notice that OP's array has 10 elements.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing

```
random_shuffle(a[0],a[9]);
```

with

```
random_shuffle(&a[0], &a[10]);
```

From: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/STL-Basics/Userandomshufflealgorithmswitharray.htm

Comment: Wouldn't it be `&a[9]`?

Answer (score 3):

`random_shuffle` takes iterators, rather than elements. Try either:

```
std::random_shuffle(a, a + 10);
```

or

```
std::random_shuffle(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

`std::random_shuffle` can be used on any pair of random access iterators, and will shuffle the elements in the range denoted by those iterators.

The error occurs because `int`s are not iterators, and so `std::random_shuffle` is unable to use the given `int`s as iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Just changing the arr to a pointer does not solve the solution. This will make the array swap to one type of permutation. This means that if you rerun the program, your array will be shuffled into the exact same way as it did in the previous run.

To fix this - the function offers a third parameter which acts as a seed. So the correct implementation of the function is as follows.

1) Have a function or a lamda that generates a random number. This will act as your seed.

```
int myrandom (int i) { return std::rand()%i;}
```

Make sure to set the seed of the internal random number generator.

```
std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );
```

2) Insert this function as the third arguement in the random_shuffle function call.

```
std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myrandom);
```

This will result in an always random shuffled array.
Make sure to include the following:

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::random_shuffle
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <ctime>        // std::time
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand, std::srand
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    random_shuffle(&a[0],&a[10]);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: For some reason this always shuffles the array in the same order. Or is this what shuffle is about?

Comment: @Koliat see Grant's answer

Comment: @2br-2b amazing it took 3 years to get an answer to my comment, and 6 years to be reminded to check the answer to the comment :-) And to be fair, '2014 was about the last time I touched C++ :-)