# How to unsort an array?

Tags: c++

I have an array of ints;

```
int bar [5] = { 10, 20, 30 };
```

Lets say instead of 3 integers, I have 10,000 in my array.

How would I unsort so that there is no order?

Comment: how about shuffle it?

Comment: Do you want *no order at all*, or just *random order*?

Comment: There is _always_ an order. The question is, what do you want that order not to be? And why?

Comment: why not just assume that it's unsorted in the first place

Comment: It's not logically possible for an array to have "no order". Please describe the problem more clearly. And keep in mind that `std::random_shuffle`, or any similar solution, might randomly leave the array in sorted order.

Comment: just random, because my professor is making us insert all the numbers into a bst and a sorted array would make the tree inefficient

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to random\_shuffle an array of int elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720134/is-it-possible-to-random-shuffle-an-array-of-int-elements)

Comment: @Shomz: No, not really.

Comment: To _unsort_ the array, it would be sufficient just to swap the first two distinctly sorted entries :/ ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And after you read the question and OP's comment?

Comment: @Shomz: Yes, after all of that. A duplicate question is just that: a question that asks the same thing as another question. It's hard to imagine suggesting that another answer called "is it possible to use `random_shuffle` in X scenario" can be the same as this answer, when _this_ OP doesn't even know that `random_shuffle` might be something he wants to use. They are not the same question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Neither this nor the duplicate question I suggested have the best titles. So yeah, if you compare like that, they make no sense, but I meant that the answer to one question completely answers the other. After all, people are here because of the answers, not the questions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm with Shonz here. _Duplicate_ doesn't means the exact question/content for me, rather having an appropriate SO Q&A , that solves the current question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`std::random_shuffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle):

```
std::random_shuffle( std::begin( bar ) , std::end( bar ) );
```

**Note:**

Is a good practice to pass your custom random number generator to the algorithm:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());

std::random_shuffle( std::begin( bar ) , std::end( bar ) , g );
```

Comment: could you show me an example in code how to use the random_shuffle for int bar [5] = { 10, 20, 30 };? I've been reading the documentation, but i'm confused.

Comment: @CodeDoctorJL There is an example in the answer, is the first code snippet. Also, the second code snippet is an example using a custom random number generator

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle your array with [std::random_shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)