# Is there a built-in function that will shuffle an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, c++20, shuffle

I am trying to create a deck of cards in C++. I store that deck in an array `array<Card, 52> deckOfCards = generateCards()`. Once I create the array, is there any way to shuffle the objects inside of it easily? For example, in Java, you could use the `shuffle()` algorithm and the objects would be shuffled.

---

People have mentioned the usage of `random_shuffle` in the comment, however `random_shuffle` has been deprecated since C++14, and removed since C++17.

Comment: Have a look at [`std::random_shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14720159/4641116

Comment: @WaisKamal at this point I'd recommend recommending `shuffle`, not `random_shuffle`. As you can see in the very documentation you linked, `random_shuffle` was deprecated and removed.

Comment: how do you implement it, could you please provide an example because when I add `#include <algorithm>` and attempt to call    `random_shuffle(deckOfCards)` i get a `No matching function for call to 'random_shuffle` red line in clion

Comment: @HadiB did you read the linked documentation and the examples below it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, C++ does have a [`shuffle()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) function. However, you must also add a random generator in there manually, which could be daunting at a first glance. However, if you don't really care the exact generator and engine being used, then this could be done simply with:

```cpp
std::shuffle(deckOfCards.begin(), deckOfCards.end(), std::default_random_engine{/*optional seed*/});
```

or

```cpp
std::shuffle(deckOfCards.begin(), deckOfCards.end(), std::random_device{});
```

Where the first one is deterministic and the second one is non-deterministic.